# electronic configuration of lanthinide series

Tags: physical-chemistry, electronic-configuration, rare-earth-elements

> Why does the 57th electron enter the $5d$ subshell in lanthanum, shouldn't it should enter the $4f$ subshell according to the Aufbau rule?
>
> Also in thorium, the 89th and 90th electrons enter the $6d$ subshell while they should enter the $5f$ subshell?